# Sometimes authentication is null (Spring security)

Tags: spring, security, authentication

I created `Authentication` in `CustomAuthenticationManager`. Everything is OK.
I have `SecurityServiceContext` where I can get User Id. 
There is a big problem, because sometimes I have `Authentication auth = null`, but sometimes It works, (for example, when project start it work, but in 10 seconds I have NPE (`Authentication auth = null`).

My CustomAuthenticationManager:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import ru.groups.entity.UserVk;
import ru.groups.service.UserService;
import java.util.*;

@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationManager implements AuthenticationProvider {

    @Autowired UserService userService;

    public Authentication loadUserByUsername(UserVk user){
        Set<String> roles = new HashSet<String>();
        roles.add("ROLE_TEACHER");
        List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = buildUserAuthority(roles);
        SecurityUser customUser = new SecurityUser(user.getId(), user.getUserName(), user.getUserAccessToken(), true, true, true, true, authorities);
        Authentication authentication =
                new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(customUser, customUser.getPassword(), authorities);
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authenticate(authentication));
        return authentication;
    }

    private List<GrantedAuthority> buildUserAuthority(Set<String> userRoles) {
        Set<GrantedAuthority> setAuths = new HashSet<GrantedAuthority>();
        for (String userRole : userRoles){
            setAuths.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(userRole));
        }
        List<GrantedAuthority> result = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>(setAuths);
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        return authentication;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> aClass) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

My SecurityServiceContext:

```
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

@Service
public class SecurityServiceContext {
    public Long getLoggedUserId() {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        return ((SecurityUser) auth.getPrincipal()).getId(); //get logged in username
    };
}
```

My SecurityUser:

```
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User;

import java.util.Collection;


public class SecurityUser extends User {
    private long id;

    SecurityUser(long id, String username, String password, boolean enabled, boolean accountNonExpired,
                      boolean credentialsNonExpired, boolean accountNonLocked,
                      Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {
        super(username, password, enabled, accountNonExpired, credentialsNonExpired, accountNonLocked, authorities);
        this.id = id;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }
}
```

My Spring config:

```
  <beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
             xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-4.0.xsd http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">


    <context:component-scan base-package="ru.groups.service.security"/>
    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider ref="customAuthenticationManager"></authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
    <global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />
</beans:beans>
```

Tomcat LocalHost Log (When I try to get the UserId).

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [mvc-dispatcher] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException] with root cause
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ru.groups.service.security.SecurityServiceContext.getLoggedUserId(SecurityServiceContext.java:11)
    at ru.groups.service.UserService.getUserDTO(UserService.java:31)
    at ru.groups.service.UserService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$fa4db602.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:720)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:281)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:655)
    at ru.groups.service.UserService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$12cb919a.getUserDTO(<generated>)
    at ru.groups.controller.UserController.getUserName(UserController.java:20)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:221)
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:136)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:110)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:817)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:731)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:968)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:859)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:844)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:121)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

My method of controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "user")
public class UserController {

    @Autowired UserService userService;
    @RequestMapping(value = "getName", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "application/json")
    public UserDTO getUserName(){
        return userService.getUserDTO();
    }
```

}

In getUserDTO() I try to get the userId :

```
long userId = context.getLoggedUserId();
```

It's my getLoggedUserId():

```
@Service
public class SecurityServiceContext {
    public Long getLoggedUserId() {
        Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        return ((SecurityUser) auth.getPrincipal()).getId(); //get logged in username
    };
}
```

But there is auth  = null (sometimes not null).

Comment: Please, somebody help me :)

Comment: Any log traces? And what about the full security context configuration?

Comment: @jlumietu I added

Comment: I tested this code in Windows (Chrome, Mozilla) and OS X (Safari). Still not working...

Comment: If user is anonymous, Authentication will be null always

Comment: @MrFylypenko But User sometimes null, sometimes not null (for 10 seconds or later). What should I do?

Comment: See `at ru.groups.controller.UserController.getUserName(UserController.java:20)`, who invoke this controller? It's your frontend, when he loaded?

Comment: @MrFylypenko getUserName it's method of controller, which invoke from front. I added him in topic.

Comment: Who knows what the problem is?

Comment: Helo @Mello007 Have you solved it? please help me